# Using GitHub's API to get lines of code added/deleted per commit (on a branch)?

Tags: github, github-api

The following gets a raw list of commits for a project's `master` branch:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<organization_name>/<repo_name/commits?page=0&per_page=30
```

**Question 1:** How can one get a similar list but for a specific `<branchname>`?

**Question 2:** The list of commits above doesn't include any data about the lines of code added/deleted per commit (i.e., a very rough productivity metric). Is there a way to get this data in the query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fetch the specific branch with `sha={branchname}` param in the [`/commits`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/) params;

> `sha` `string`    SHA or branch to start listing commits from. Default: the repository’s default branch (usually master).

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<org_name>/<repo_name>/commits?sha=<branchName>&page=0&per_page=30
```

---

To get per-file specific changes for each commit, you'd need to check `url` variable for each commit entity in the response of above URL. From that [new endpoint call](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit), you will get a more detailed information of that single commit. `files` variable in there will contain the changes contained in that commit. Both added & removed codes per file.

> An example with my repo;
>
> https://api.github.com/repos/buraequete/orikautomation/commits?sha=master&page=0&per_page=30
>
> If we get the first commits `url`;
>
> https://api.github.com/repos/buraequete/orikautomation/commits/89792e6256dfccc5e9151d81bf04145ba02fef8f
>
> Which contains the changes you want in `files` variable as a list.
>
> ```
> "files": [
>     {
>       "sha": "8aaaa7de53bed57fc2865d2fd84897211c3e70b6",
>       "filename": "lombok.config",
>       "status": "added",
>       "additions": 1,
>       "deletions": 0,
>       "changes": 1,
>       "blob_url": "https://github.com/buraequete/orikautomation/blob/89792e6256dfccc5e9151d81bf04145ba02fef8f/lombok.config",
>       "raw_url": "https://github.com/buraequete/orikautomation/raw/89792e6256dfccc5e9151d81bf04145ba02fef8f/lombok.config",
>       "contents_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/buraequete/orikautomation/contents/lombok.config?ref=89792e6256dfccc5e9151d81bf04145ba02fef8f",
>       "patch": "@@ -0,0 +1 @@\n+lombok.accessors.chain = true"
>     },
>     ...
> ]
> ```

Sorry but I don't think there is a way to get those per file changes in the original `/commits` endpoint call, you have to do multiple calls...

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I am not sure why github requires an extra call, wastes everyones resources...